Showing there is a point in a subset of a vector space that is closest to a point in that vector space
The following is Exercise 6.A.32 from Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition, by Sheldon Axler:

Suppose that $E$ is a subset of $V$ with the property that $u, v \in E$ implies $\frac12(u + v) \in E$. Let $w \in V$.
Show that there is at most one point in $E$ that is closest to $w$.
In other words, show that there is at most one $u \in E$ such that
$$\left\lVert w - u \right\rVert \leq \left\lVert w - x \right\rVert$$
for all $x \in E$.

Axler (in the third edition) hints that we can prove this using the following result:

Suppose $u, v, w \in V.$ Then
$$ \left\lVert w - \frac12(u+v) \right\rVert ^2 = \frac{\left\lVert w - u \right\rVert ^2 + \left\lVert w - v \right\rVert ^2}{2} - \frac{\left\lVert u - v \right\rVert}{4} $$

All of the proofs that I could find online seemed to me that they only showed uniqueness (by using the above result) without showing existence. Thus, my concern here is to first show that at least one such $u$ must exist.
My naive attempt at this was the following:

Let $x \in E$ be any element in $E$.
Then, we clearly have $\left\lVert w - x \right\rVert \leq \left\lVert w - x \right\rVert$.
That is, for any $x \in E$, we can find a $u \in E$, namely $u = x$, such that $\left\lVert w - u \right\rVert \leq \left\lVert w - x \right\rVert$.
Hence, showing the existence.

But I don't think this is correct -- if I'm understanding the question correctly, $u$ needs to remain the same regardless of what $x \in E$ is.
Could someone guide me through a correct proof of this just showing the existence part?

Suppose for contradiction that $u$ and $v$ are both "closest" to $w$. Then what can you say about how close $\frac{1}{2}(u+v)$ is to $w$? If you can argue that $\frac{1}{2}(u+v)$ is closer to $w$ than either $u$ or $v$, then you have a contradiction.

@AlanChung But doesn't that just show uniqueness? Why should such a $u$ exist in the first place?

@PaulAsh If $E$ is closed & convex (subset of a Hilbert space), then existence can be proved by showing that any minimising sequence is Cauchy. I finite dimensions a compactness argument shows existence (for any non empty closed set).

@copper.hat Is $E$ convex in this case? I thought convexity meant that if $u, v \in E$, then $\alpha u + (1- \alpha) v \in E$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbf{F}$.

@PaulAsh I am not sure what this case refers to. Convexity means for all $\alpha \in [0,1]$ (I don't know what $F$ refers to). Basically if $x,y \in E$ then $[x,y] \subset E$. The mid point condition above implies uniqueness, but does not imply existence. You need some closedness criterion to show existence.

You are looking at that Exercise wrong.
It says "Show that there is at most one point in $E$ that is closest to $w$."
That Point might not Exist , hence we can not show the Existence at all.
Consider this Example :
$V=(0,8)$
$E_0=[4.5,5.5]\cup[6.5,7.5]$
$E_1=[1,2]$
$E_2=(1,2)$
Consider $E_0$ : It will not have the Property [ When $u \in E_0 , v \in E_0$ , then $[u + v]/2 \in E_0$ ]
Consider $E_1$ : It has the Property. Let $w=6$ , then the closest $u \in E_1$ is $u=2$. When the $v \in E_1$ is closest too , then $u=v$ , which is the Uniqueness.
Consider $E_2$ : It has the Property. Let $w=6$ , then the closest $u \in E_2$ can not exist at all. Naturally , the $v \in E_2$ can not exist too , then it is immaterial whether $u=v$ , to check the Uniqueness.
Hence the Exercise is to take the $u$ & check whether the $v$ can have $u \not = v$ or it must necessarily occur that $u = v$

In other words, the theorem isn't claiming existence.

That is Correct , @NateEldredge , where at most one will naturally include Zero there.

Oh jeez, you’re absolutely correct! Thank you for the elaboration that we’re not claiming existence.
